# Squid Proxy IP address while making webservice calls

Tags: php, squid

I have a call to a web services where the vendor has the IP restriction. My ip is added in the vendor's white-list, When i make the a simple curl call to vendor's API it works.

Whereas, When i do the same via squid proxy, It gives me invalid IP. I checked my squid log, its send my IP address as 127.0.0.1 which might be the reason why its not working. so anybody has any solution for this.

So how to bypass this issue and send my Static IP rather the local IP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your router, either configure a static IP for your clinets (using MAC address) or configure your clients with a static IP address. More about implementation of it, can be found here [Ubuntu Linux convert DHCP network configuration to static IP configuration](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-ubuntu-linux-convert-dhcp-network-configuration-to-static-ip-configuration.html) .